# is the serial Number of a device unique?

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I have multiple devices connected via a virtual serial port to my device. I want to know what specific device is connected to which COM port.

with

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

reslt = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()


for i in reslt:
    print(i.hwid)
    print(i)
```

I get

```
ACPI\PNP0501\5&15D725F4&0
COM5 - Kommunikationsanschluss (COM5)
USB VID:PID=0403:6001 SER=MAO74LCRA
COM3 - USB Serial Port (COM3)
USB VID:PID=0403:6001 SER=FT41M1WWA
COM6 - USB Serial Port (COM6)
```

Some how the Vendor/ Product ID are the same, but the Serial is different.
So are the Serial numbers from the devices `( SER=MAO74LCRA, SER=FT41M1WWA)` unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Serial numbers from devices are unique. That’s their purpose, identification.